# Set an attribute on a request before it's handled

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2, webob, gae-python27

My App Engine application has a custom user model.  This model is accessed frequently in the application code. I would like to simplify the code by injecting a model instance into each authenticated request before the request is handled  (similar to the `process_request` method of Django middleware classes).

I am using the App Engine Python2.7 standard runtime with webapp2 as the framework.

I tried creating a WSGI middleware callable that modified the WSGI environ dictionary and defined a `webapp_add_wsgi_middleware` function `appengine_config.py` to add the middleware, but the middleware did not run until after the request had been processed by the app.

How can I modify the request before it's handled by the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found was to create a subclass of `webapp2.WSGIApplication` and have that modify the `environ` dictionary before calling the superclass to run the app.  To set the instance as an attribute of the request, rather than having to access it via Request.environ, I added it to the `environ`'s 'webob.adhoc_attrs' value.  This is because webapp2's Request class inherits from webob's, which in turn inherits from a [mixin class](https://github.com/Pylons/webob/blob/1.2.3/webob/request.py#L1378) that manages attribute access.

Here's an example application that sets an attribute on all requests:

```
import webapp2


class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        try:
            foo = self.request.foo
        except AttributeError:
            foo = 'Default'
        self.response.write('Hello %s' % foo)


routes = [('/', Handler)]


class MyWSGIApplication(webapp2.WSGIApplication):

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        adhoc_attrs = {'foo': 'Foo'}
        if 'webob.adhoc_attrs' in environ:
            environ['webob.adhoc_attrs'].update(adhoc_attrs)
        else:
            environ['webob.adhoc_attrs'] = adhoc_attrs
        return super(MyWSGIApplication, self).__call__(environ, start_response)


app = MyWSGIApplication(routes)
```